# How to create combo chart in ssrs with both bar chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

Is it possible to create Bar chart like in the figure using SSRS, IF yes can you please tell me the steps to create it. It consists of two barchart ias a combo bar chart in excel .

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, it's not possible.  If you simply want a bar chart with 2 different series groups, that's possible, but not what you have depicted.